# Layout position error after deleting Images.xcassets in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, ios7, autolayout

### Steps to generate the problem

1) In **Xcode 5, OS X Mavericks**, create an iOS **"Empty Application"**, set Product Name as **"empty_project"**, set Organization Name as **"org_name"**, set Company Identifier as **"com.org_name"**, leave Class Prefix empty, set Devices as **"Universal"**, uncheck **"Use Core Data"**. Click **"Next"**, then **"Create"**.

2) Set the **`Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting`** as **`NO`** for both the `empty_project` project and the `empty_project target in the "Build Settings" page.

3) Go to `AppDelegate.m`, change that `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method as this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController new] autorelease];

    UIView* v1 = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 568 - 20)] autorelease];
    v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:.4 blue:1 alpha:1]; // pink color
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: v1];

    UIWebView* v2 = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 568 - 20 - 45 - 49)] autorelease];
    v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1]; // light green color
    NSURL *urlToLoad = nil;
    urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"]];
    NSURLRequest *requestOBj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToLoad];
    [v2 loadRequest:requestOBj];
    [v1 addSubview:v2];

    return YES;
}
```

4) Run simulator to see the result. There is from top to bottom, a 20-point high status bar with white background, a 45-point high pink margin (using navigation bar height), a 454-point high UIWebView view (because 568 - 20 - 45 - 49 = 454), a 49-point high pink margin in the bottom (using tab bar height):

[image]

Scroll down to end of the web page to see if the bottom boundary is set as expected:

[image]

5) Quit the simulator, and delete the **Images.xcassets** folder using "Remove Reference".

6) Run simulator again to see the result. The layout is changed as shown here:

There are two black margins in top and bottom of the screen, even the status bar moved down.

[image]

and scroll to the end of the web page, we have some trailing part hidden by the bottom margin:

[image]

7) Quit simulator and add back the **Images.xcassets** folder and then run simulator again we can have the original correct layout.

### Discussion

I guess I've touched something related to Auto Layout in iOS 7. I have another project that was created in Xcode 4.6 and somehow being used in Xcode 5 now, without the **Images.xcassets** folder, and there's some layout problem too in that project.

How can I solve this problem? Do I have to turn off Auto Layout or something?

### Reference

[Apple's Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've deleted a 4-inch launch image (it's kept in `Images.xcassets`). It's a hint for Xcode to build an app only for 3.5-inch displays.

Comment: Hi @ArkadiuszHolko, but in the empty project there seems to be an empty `Images.xcassets` folder.

Comment: @congliu: Hmm, I've just created an Empty Project and it has a LaunchImage (see [the screenshot](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5184129/Screenshots/lk_~.png)). [Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1) a documentation of Asset Catalogs.

Comment: Hi again (...because when I put at_your_name in the beginning, the at symbol will be ignored after I click on Add Comment >_< ) @ArkadiuszHolko, your screenshot is the same as mine, isn't that means empty or pure white background?

Comment: @congliu: Yes, it's an empty image but it's present. This behavior is explained [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/12/31/retina-4-support.html). The only difference now is that images are kept in the Assets Catalog.